# ERROR: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer - Electron

Tags: electron-builder

I have a VUE + PHP project. When I run npm run dev (on localhost) everything is ok, but when I try to run npm build I have problems. The project code is quite old (3 years old) and a lot of the syntax is outdated. I catch error :
┏ Electron -------------------
(node:148844) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '/home/ds/Antaros/redbutton/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node'. This is deprecated, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.

Under project NODE V10, NPM V6.

I read everything that is on this resource, but there is no solution, I read the reference at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397, but I still did not understand how to update the code in the context. Tried npm install @serialport/bindings@latest but no success. I can't update dependencies because I'll have to rewrite all the code to fit the new syntax.

Added app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;(true) - does't work

Please tell me how to configure the electron module?

I am attaching package.json for review and a screenshot with errors

```
{
  "name": "redbutton",
  "productName": "redbutton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "RedButton",
  "main": "./dist/main/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "build": "npm run compile && electron-builder",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.vue"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Vladimir Yazliev",
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "npmRebuild": false,
    "productName": "redbutton",
    "directories": {
      "output": "out/build"
    },
    "linux": {
      "files": [
        "!.gitignore",
        "!.idea/*",
        "!out/*",
        "!src/*",
        "!dist/*",
        "!.redbutton/*",
        "build/**",
        "migrations/*"
      ],
      "asar": true,
      "icon": "build/icon.png",
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "AppImage",
          "arch": [
            "armv7l",
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "electronWebpack": {
    "title": "RedButton",
    "renderer": {
      "template": "src/index.html",
      "webpackConfig": "webpack.render.config.js"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 3 versions",
    "ExplorerMobile >= 10",
    "chrome 49",
    "IE >= 10"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "drivelist": "^8.0.10",
    "electron-download-manager": "^2.1.2",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.7",
    "electron-shutdown-command": "0.0.8",
    "electron-simple-updater": "^2.0.8",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "excel4node": "^1.7.2",
    "executive": "^1.6.3",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "loudness": "^0.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "pi-wifi": "^1.2.0",
    "serialport": "^8.0.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
    "sqlite": "^3.0.3",
    "ulid": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-touch": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vue-touch-keyboard": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
    "electron": "^8.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.0",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.7.4",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "node-abi": "^2.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postinstall": "^0.7.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

```
"use strict";

import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";
import { format as formatUrl } from "url";

const DownloadManager = require("electron-download-manager");

DownloadManager.register({
  downloadFolder: process.env.PWD,
});

const isDevelopment = true;
// const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

let mainWindow;

function createMainWindow() {
  let windowOptions;

  if (isDevelopment) {
    windowOptions = {
      width: 1280,
      height: 800,
      icon: path.join(__dirname, "build", "icon.png"),
      title: "RedButton",
      webPreferences: {
        devTools: isDevelopment,
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
    };
  } else {
    windowOptions = {
      icon: path.join(__dirname, "build", "icon.png"),
      title: "RedButton",
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      frame: false,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      webPreferences: {
        devTools: isDevelopment,
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
    };
  }

  const window = new BrowserWindow(windowOptions);

  if (isDevelopment) {
    window.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    window.setFullScreen(true);
  }

  if (isDevelopment) {
    window.loadURL(`http://localhost:${process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_WDS_PORT}`);
  } else {
    window.loadURL(
      formatUrl({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file",
        slashes: true,
      })
    );
  }

  window.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  window.webContents.on("devtools-opened", () => {
    window.focus();
    setImmediate(() => {
      window.focus();
    });
  });

  return window;
}

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
  }
});

app.on("ready", () => {
  mainWindow = createMainWindow();
  // app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;
});
```

I read everything that is on this resource, but there is no solution, I read the reference at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397, but I still did not understand how to update the code in the context. Tried npm install @serialport/bindings@latest but no success. I can't update dependencies because I'll have to rewrite all the code to fit the new syntax.

Added app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;(true) - does't work

Comment: I have a solution! Just update electron for 9 V